# How to remove several elements of a list by the index which can be changed each time?

Tags: python, list, indexing, del

I have a list like below:

```
A =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

After using enumerate I have the following list:

```
A = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

After checking a condition, I realized that I don't need the elements with index 0 and 2.
It means that my condition returns a list like below which can be different each time:

```
condA = [(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

I know that I can use `del` or `.pop()` to remove an element from a list.
However, I was wondering how can I read the numbers like (0) and (2) in my `condA list` and remove those elements from my original list. 
I don't want to enter the 0 and 2 in my code because each time they would be different.

The result would be like this:

```
A_reduced = [2, 4]
```

Comment: Honestly??? Just summarize it to what your input is and what the desired output is. And please do us (and yourself) a favor, and get rid of all those redundant parenthesis.

Comment: @Blorgbeard the point is that I can look at the condA list and identify the elements that I don't need. But there must be a more efficient way to remove the elements that condA shows.

Comment: @goodvibration Done. sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the index from the condA list and create the list of that number, the list of indices of elements to be removed will be like:

```
rm_lst = [x[0] for x in condA]
```

Now, to remove the elements from your main list:

```
A = [(0, ((11), (12))), (1, ((452), (54))), (2, ((545), (757))), (3, ((42), (37)))]
A_reduced = [x[1] for x in A if x[0] not in rm_lst]
```

Final Code:

```
A = [(0, ((11), (12))), (1, ((452), (54))), (2, ((545), (757))), (3, ((42), (37)))] 
condA = [(0, ((11), (452))), (2, ((545), (757)))]
rm_lst = [x[0] for x in condA]
A_reduced = [x[1] for x in A if x[0] not in rm_lst]
print(A_reduced)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete elements from list inside loop, you should iterate from last to first:

```
for i in range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1):
    if true:  # replace with condition
        del A[i]
```

**Upd.**

You can also use list comprehension for this, **but** you should invert you condition (`A[i][0] != 11` => `A[i][0] == 11`):

```
A = [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if inverted_condition]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC maybe a function is the correct way:

```
A =  [1, 2, 3, 4]

def remove_items(lis, idx):
    lis2=lis.copy()
    [lis2.pop(i) for i in idx]
    return lis2

A_reduced=remove_items(A,[0,2])
```

Output:

```
Out[32]: [2, 3]
```

You can add any list of indexes you want, and it'll drop them from the list. (If they exist)

Edit: Adjusted to your new values, and modified the function so you also keep your original list (if that's needed)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `condA`, pop the element off the list `A`. You need a counter to decrease the indexes, since the size of `A` is shrinking. Make sure to sort `condA`:

```
A =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
condA = [(0, 1), (2, 3)]

i = 0
for item in condA:
    A.pop(item[0]-i)
    i+=1
#result: [2, 4]
```